# "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to integrate with a bare bones application but I keep running into this error after applying our integration key and making sure our application not only looked at the Demo API but as well was DEMO within the dashboard.

```
DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling Login: {

  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",

  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
```

I verified that all the credentials are exactly as displayed and all have been correct. The apiclient is the correct value to pass to the demo if I am correct. Nothing has been changed from the sample other then the parameters I need to throw in anyway. The application is exactly what the example is of:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DocuSign.eSign.Api;
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendAPiCall();
        }
        public void SendAPiCall()
        {
            string username = "[*]";
            string password = "[*]";
            string integratorKey = "[*]";

            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
            Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

            var config = new Configuration(apiClient);
            var authApi = new AuthenticationApi(config);


            string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";
            Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

            // we will retrieve this from the login API call
            string accountId = null;

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // STEP 1: LOGIN API        
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // login call is available in the authentication api 
            LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

            // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
            accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nick,

The culprit is the following code :

```
var authApi = new AuthenticationApi(config);
```

Instead, don't specify the configuration. Try this, it will fix your error :

```
var authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
```

The reason is that you already specified the API configuration in your code with the following line :

```
Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
```